# What example is there for ASSUME dataregister : qualifiedtype [, dataregister : qualifiedtype]?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

MASM describes several forms of the ASSUME directive and only shows a couple of examples. The one I could not find any example is this one:

```
ASSUME dataregister : qualifiedtype [, dataregister : qualifiedtype]
```

I found no information on `dataregister`. Does anybody have an example of the `ASSUME` directive in this form? What is a `dataregister`?

Answer (score 4):

It's used to give a type (`qualifiedtype`) to a memory operand using the specified general purpose register (`dataregister`) when it's not specified explicitly.

MASM can often infer the size of a memory operand based on the size of the other operand. In the following example, MASM knows that the destination memory operand must be DWORD sized because the source operand is DWORD sized:

```
mov     [edx], eax
```

However sometimes MASM can't do this, either because there is no other operand or because the other operand doesn't have a known size:

```
inc     [ebx]          ; error A2023:instruction operand must have size
mov     [edx], 0       ; error A2070:invalid instruction operands
```

The solution normally is to make the size of the memory operand explicit:

```
inc     BYTE PTR [ebx]
mov     DWORD PTR [edx], 0
```

However you can tell MASM that when a given register is used in memory operand that it should assume the memory operand is of a given type:

```
ASSUME  ebx:PTR BYTE
ASSUME  edx:PTR DWORD
inc     [ebx]
mov     [edx], 0
```

This can be handy when you need explicitly specify the size of memory operand a lot, but stylistically I wouldn't recommend this as it makes your code less clear. The one case where it might be worthwhile is with structures, as the syntax for using them with memory operands can be a bit messy:

```
mov     (linked_list_node PTR [ecx]).prev, esi
mov     (linked_list_node PTR [ecx]).next, 0
mov     (linked_list_node PTR [ecx]).data, al
```

```
ASSUME  ecx:PTR linked_list_node
mov     [ecx].prev, esi
mov     [ecx].next, 0
mov     [ecx].data, al
```

I don't know why memory operands use the `type PTR` order while ASSUME uses the `PTR type` order.